# ¿Es posible en GIT crear una rama de un repositorio a partir de una carpeta del mismo?

Tags: git, github, control-de-versiones, tfs

¿Es posible en GIT crear una rama de un repositorio a partir de una carpeta del mismo? Es decir, ¿Se puede convertir un directorio a una rama al estilo de TFSVC?
Si es posible, ¿Cómo se hace?

Comment: O sea, quieres tomar solo un directorio de un proyecto en git ya existente para convertirlo en su propio proyecto en git descartando el resto de la historia del proyecto (no digo que lo vayas a descartar en el repo actual... solo que la historia de la rama que quieres no toma en cuenta el resto del proyecto)?

Comment: Si la respuesta a mi pregunta en el comentario anterior es **si**, entonces tienes que usar filter-repo. https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo